# Monitor says Out of Range

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu

Since my last thread, I've tried installing Lubuntu once again on my old PC, though with DVD now because my PC couldn't boot from USB. So the DVD works fine. I have checked the MD5 before burning the iso to the DVD. Inserted the DVD, changed the boot priority to DVD and it boots up from it. The thing is I select the option Install Lubuntu and then it shows something written like a code, and then shows Lubuntu logo/text with a light blue screen. Now the thing is, after this step, the installation wouldn't go any further because my monitor says - OUT OF RANGE 45.4kHZ  /159Hz. It just stays so. Doesn't proceed any further.

One more thing, I actually set nomodeset option(enabled it) first and had the same issue. Then disabled it and still am getting the same issue.

Could someone help me out?

EDIT:I used to have 1024x768 resolution when I had XP. Now I'm without any OS as well and only option is to install Lubuntu.

Comment: Are you trying with Lubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

Comment: I'm really sorry to mention that, it's 16.04.1. - desktop.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou 16.04.1

Comment: What processor, and how much memory does this machine have? Cheers, Al

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find anything else on the web apart the `nomodeset` option. Are you able to download and install Lubuntu 14.04 instead?

Comment: @heynnema - Pentium 4, 1.4 GB RAM. Used to run XP, though. ;)

Comment: @ThanosApostolou I'll try that as well. I have the .iso downloaded, haven't burned it yet. Shall do and tell today. 
Thanks guys for helping.

Comment: Is your video monitor connected to a video card, or onboard video? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema and Thanos - I installed Lubuntu 14.04 successfully on my PC and now I'm on it. Can I know how I can update my softwares and also check if they're already updated or not?

Comment: @AmalS.Kuriakose Run the command `sudo apt-get update` and it will show you if there are packages to be updated. Then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update the packages (`apt-get dist-upgrade` upgrades the packages and it's almost similar to `apt-get upgrade` but I prefer it). You can also run the Software Updater application and it will search for updates. Keep in mind, that you won't get the latest versions to most software, but just security updates (due to Ubuntu's policy), so if you need newer software try again when Lubuntu 16.04.2 is out or search for PPAs.